# Intellij SDK Settings checked into a source repository

Tags: git, intellij-idea

We have our Intellij (13) project settings checked into a git repository. I want to configure Intellij's Python interpreter within the project. To do this I need to add the SDK under "Platform Settings" and then select it in "Facets" under "Project Settings". The latter is checked-in, but the former is a global setting which we haven't checked in. If I commit the project settings change, other developers will merge that change but then Intellij will overwrite it because the SDK name is not configured in platform settings.

How can I get around this? It seems like the only way is to have a script modify the global settings files, but that's just nasty.

Comment: Well, my previous experience tells that storing IDE settings in a project repository is not a bright idea. If you wish to make sure that all your co-workers use a "compatible" set of settings, you should create and publish a formal requirements and code style guide, and then force everybody to follow this style. You may also use some kind of code beautifiers etc to automate this process.

Comment: I'm not trying to enforce style, I'm trying to ensure that we can setup the project to be pointed to a Python interpreter.

Comment: Each developer may have a slightly different environment settings, including python location, installed modules etc.

Comment: We're in a position where we can quite reasonably create a common location with a symlink.

Answer (score 1):

Could you make use of Git Hooks, e.g.: the post-checkout hook which would then set these settings for you? Of course there would be a script to do this, but it would be executed automatically